# Manga where male child main character is neglected by family for having no skill but is strong, and sister is now the main in the family

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic

The main character can use the sword very well, to the point he can use a stick for the sword skills. Eventually, he meets a girl who struggles with magic. Later, his sister who loves him sees that he has the skill and they spar; he wins and they go back to being together.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? What colour was the sister's hair? And what did you mean by the sister now being "the main" in the family? Did you mean that she was the head of the family? The favoured child? Something else?

Comment: the favoured/all expectations on her.

Comment: Mushoku no Eiyuu - Character is explicitly classless. Has an affectionate sister. But he's not really kicked out, and his sister doesn't take over as far as I can tell. I don't think this is it.

Comment: I Think I'll Hide My True Ability to the Last Moment - No mention of skills or classes, but MC is pretending to be very weak and berated by his family. Sister loves him and is explicitly very skilled with the sword. I don't recall them sparring, nor a girl that struggles with magic. The "stick" bit could be a misremembering of him fighting with a training spear. Unless I'm forgetting a lot of events, this isn't likely either.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be [The Magician Who Rose From Failure](https://j-novel.club/series/the-magician-who-rose-from-failure-manga)? He is disinherited in favour of his younger sister (who adores him) due to having low “aether”, meets a girl mage by chance and helps her study magic.

Comment: Close but the mc is mainly using sword techniques, and no magic to my memory.